# Is it faster to sort dates or sort strings in SPSS? If so, by how much?

Tags: performance, sorting, date, spss

I have a dataset of around 5 million records. The dates are read in as strings. They are in the form MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS. I am only interested in the date part of it so I read them in as (A10) format which effectively trims the time.

I then do `ALTER TYPE DateVar (SDATE10)`. I do this as I thought sorting dates would be quicker but I can't find confirmation of this.

Is there a way to time SPSS commands to work out questions like this?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself and see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way I can think of is to use python for the timestamps, and normal SPSS syntax for the sorting - just to replicate real-life conditions

```
***Start timer, in python.    
begin program.
import time
start = time.time()
end program.
***go out of python, into normal SPSS syntax, and do your stuff.

/*Put the syntax you want to test here

***get back to python, stop timer, and calculate time difference.
begin program.
end = time.time()
print("It took ",end - start, " seconds")
end program.
```

Check the output log, and it will show you the time.

Not very scientific, but quick and easy.
I recommend re-starting SPSS between tests - just to be sure one test is not affecting the other.

From my experience, `alter type` does something that affects code execution times. Not sure what, but everything seems slower after an `alter type`. So you might also consider saving and re-opening after using `alter type`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried what you suggested.

I ran a few times with different 'options' it does look like alter type slows things down though not by much. It also doesn't seem to make a huge amount of difference sorting dates or strings. The times I got for each fluctuated +- 5 secs which meant they averaged out to be about equal.

I think I'll leave them as strings to avoid the alter type in this particular case. In other instances they need to be date to make other things simpler, but here I just use them to sort and only once.

Comment: You can use this logic for timing anything. It also possible to write more complex programs, that would automatically run the same syntax a number of times, and present you with the average time (and maybe confidence intervals, or other statistics. But I guess you were after a quick-fix, not an elaborate statistics-based method, right ? :)

Comment: Exactly, I briefly considered how to expand it to provide a larger sample size etc. but since the couple of times I already recorded were reasonably similar it didn't seem worth it (just now)

Answer (score 1):

You should keep the Date format, because:

1. Dates In spss are actually numbers (formatted in the display as dates but just numbers all the same). Sorting numbers is faster than sorting strings.
2. In any case, sorting by dates as strings will not order the file by dates (eg. "12-OCT-2017" > "11-NOV-2017").
3. See another good reason in @horace_vr's comment below.

Comment: What about memory usage ? I believe numbers take less space than strings (bytes per character), and this may become relevant on very large datafiles, which seems to be the case for the OP.